# Why is UIScrollView contentSize ignored in IB but works when I set it in my viewDidAppear method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview

I've been struggling with this for a while and thought to myself I'd make my scrollView an outlet and try to set the content size in viewDidLoad but that didn't work.

I then tried viewWillAppear and no luck again. With out any hope I thought I'd might as well try out viewDidAppear and it worked.

Prior to this the scrollView would only scroll slightly and was not taking my contentSize in IB into account.

Is there a setting in IB that stops this from happening?

Comment: as rob explains it's fundamentally because of the ORDER things happen in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have autolayout enabled for your storyboard (or xib).

Auto layout sets the scroll view's `contentSize` based on constraints between the scroll view and its subviews.  I believe this happens in the scroll view's `layoutSubviews` method.

Methods are called in this order:

```
view controller's viewDidLoad
view controller's viewWillAppear:
view controller's viewWillLayoutSubviews
each view's layoutSubviews, from the root view down
view controller's viewDidLayoutSubviews
view controller's viewDidAppear:
```

When you tried setting `contentSize` in `viewDidLoad` and in `viewWillAppear:`, it didn't work because the scroll view's `layoutSubviews` overrode it later.  When you set it in `viewDidAppear:`, you overrode what the scroll view did.

The correct way to handle this is to create constraints between the scroll view and its children.  If you want the scroll view to scroll vertically, you need constraints between its top edge and a child, and between its bottom edge and a child, and enough constraints between children to determine the overall content height.

You can find Apple's official documentation in [Technical Note TN2154: UIScrollView And Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html).

You might also find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgeNPRBrB18&feature=youtu.be) helpful.

Comment: I done this correctly. But my constraints were being ignored. I had 0 yellow warnings. I then decided to just set the content size for the second time but programmatically instead and then things worked.